# Subset Sum for Complex Type

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Below is the subset sum calculation that gives the result for simple array using LINQ.

Read from http://algorithmicalley.com/archive/2010/05/02/the-subset-sum-problem.aspx

```
          List<int> list = new List<int> { 60, 45, 45, 45, 45, 30 };

           var subsets = from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << list.Count)

          select

              from i in Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count)

              where (m & (1 << i)) != 0

              select list[i];

          var result=subsets.First(set => set.Sum() == 180);
```

This result gives expected `45,45,45,45`

But i want to this subset sum with Complex Object property, rather than int values

```
        List<Group> groups = new List<Group>{new Group{Count=60},
            new Group{Count=45},new Group{Count=45},new Group{Count=45},
            new Group{Count=45},new Group{Count=30},new Group{Count=60},
            new Group{Count=60},new Group{Count=15}
        };
```

Then

```
        var subsets = from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << groups.Count)

                      select

                          from i in Enumerable.Range(0, groups.Count)

                          where (m & (1 << i)) != 0

                          select groups[i];

        List<Group> subset =?????????? something like group.Count.Sum()==180
```

**LINQ or any implementations are welcome. I have no idea about how to deal this LINQ to get my result.**

Comment: Why are you using `Range` here at all? Why are you not using [`Average`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx)?

Comment: @Oded, I need to take some of the group which gives Total Count exactly 180. I got this LINQ does the same, but only with the supplied integer array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = subsets.First(set => set.Select(s => s.Count).Sum() == 180);
```

Just a note, your current algorithm will yield 36 such sets that sum to `180`, but you only care about the first. Not sure if that's intended or not.

Additionally, if you change your original query to include this constraint, you only end up iterating until you find a valid subset rather than continuing to build all 512 possible subsets:

```
var result = (from m in Enumerable.Range(0, 1 << groups.Count)
    select
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, groups.Count)
    where (m & (1 << i)) != 0
    select groups[i])
    .First(set => set.Select(s => s.Count).Sum() == 180);
```